# Unable To create new table in database

Tags: laravel-5

I created two tables in database. But now I get error to create another one. Third table can not add in the database. But migrate successfully.

I tried all those thinks which are mentioned below:

`php artisan make:migration create_book_table`

`php artisan migrate`

after that I get an error:

```
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `Admins` add unique `admins_emai
  l_unique`(`email`))
```

Then I tried:

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

**but it's still not fixed.**

**Here is the migration file**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBookTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone-number');
            $table->string('checkIn');
            $table->string('checkOut');
            $table->string('Room');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this line of code in your AppServiceProvider.php file in the boot function:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand on which file I should add those code

Comment: the path for the file is: app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: I'm glad I could help!